# Metabase API with Ruby - How to get question data by adding filters via the Metabase API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metabase

I would like to get in my rails 7 app data from metabase. I have no issue for retrieving data from a question. But I can't find a way to send filters to the API.

For example : I would like to do a call API to the table "GRID" and filter it on multiple "FIELD ID" values "513", "556", "928".

An other issue is that the data load is very big (more than 1 000 000 lines). How may I retrieve those data to my app ?

The Metabase Doc. does not bring sufficient info and the gem metabase-ruby is not working on my app.

I am actually using HTTP call to use the API.

I may give you more info if needed.